# Jasmine error '$digest already in progress'

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I developed an app with the IBM Mobilefirst platform (ionic, AngularJS) and now I want to test this app with the Jasmine framework.

The following code is a part of my controller which I want to test:

```
$scope.method= function(...) {
    ServiceSvc.insertProduct().then(function() {
        $scope.finishsavingAdding = true;
        $scope.finishsavingDeleting = false;

        ServiceSvc.getAllProducts().then(function(data) {
            $scope.product= data.invocationResult.resultSet;
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete'); 
            $scope.$apply(); }) })}
```

I tried to make an unit test with the following code and it throws me this error:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

```
it("should call method", function(){
    $scope.method();
    expect(ServiceSvcMock.insertProduct).toHaveBeenCalled();

    var data = {invocationResult: {resultSet:"test"}};
    deferred.resolve(data);          
    $scope.$apply();

    expect($scope.finishsavingDeleting).toBe(false);    
    expect(ServiceSvcMock.getAllProducts).toHaveBeenCalled();   
});
```

I have already read other threads on Stack Overflow but they did not help me.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `$scope.$apply();` shouldn't required if its `getAllProducts()` is using `$q`/`$http`/`$resource`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown when you use `$scope.$apply();`. This is because, that piece of your code(which contains `$scope.$apply()`) is already in angular's digest cycle.

Remove `$scope.$apply()` and it should work fine.

Comment: thank you for the fast answer, but when i remove the apply-line from my test, finishsavingDeleting will be undefined and ServiceSvcMock.getAllProducts will not be called. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Remove the line from $scope.method

Comment: Thank you it worked :) currently i can not upvote your comment but  i will do it later when i have more reputations

Comment: @JavaAndroider please accept the answer if you deem it correct. :)

Comment: You cannot upvote, but you can accept it as the right answer.